# Backstack for newInstance

Tags: android

I have 3 activities : A (launcher), B and C. I have specified A's launchMode (in manifest) as singleInstance. A has a button to go to B, B has a button to launch C, C has a button to launch A - all using default "standard" mode of invocation.

I take following steps :

- Launch app -> A -> Launch B -> B -> Launch C -> C -> Launch A -> A ->
  Launch B -> C

This takes me to C (and not B) ! I can't get why.

Another series of steps :

- Launch app -> A -> Launch B -> B -> Launch C -> C -> Launch A -> A ->
  Launch B -> C -> Launch A -> A -> Launch B -> C -> Back -> B ->Back
  -> A -> Back -> Exit

Where did the rest of the stack go ? And how come B came in the back-stack (in the last steps) while I did not encounter while going forward.

Another doubt is that by newInstance I thought a new task will be created for A atmost twice - and I should be able to see that in the recent tasks - but I cannot. How do I "see" a task ?

EDIT : Adding relevant code (Adding only relevant code for brevity sake) :

```
**Manifest**
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.backstack.B"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_b" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.backstack.A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.backstack.C"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_c" >
    </activity>
```

A.java - launchB is set as onClick member in layout xml

```
public void launchB(View v){
    Intent i= new Intent(this, B.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

B.java

```
public void launchC(View v){
    Intent i= new Intent(this, C.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

C.java

```
public void launchA(View v){
    Intent i= new Intent(this, A.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Posting your code would be useful.

Comment: I guess it might be something minor mistake like you maybe copy pasted code from one activity to another. please check all the button onClick() method if properly coded..